# Image processing surveillance camera

Tags: image-processing

I was given this question on a job interview and think I really messed up. I was wondering how others would go about it so I could learn from this experience.

You have one image from a surveillance video located at an airport which includes line of people waiting for check-in. You have to assess if the line is big/crowded and therefore additional clerks are necessary. You can assume anything that may help your answer. What would you do?
I told them I would try to

- segment the area containing people from the rest by edge detection
- use assumptions on body contour such as relative height/width to denoise unwanted edges
- use color knowledges; but then they asked how to do that and I didn't know

Comment: You can't mess up an interview by saying you don't know the answer to a question. Either you went to the interview full knowing that you don't know the domain they need programmers in, or the ad was badly written. If they require programmers with knowledge about image analysis, and not just knowing that it is possible, but the actual math and signal processing behind it, then the ad (or whatever you read that made you turn up for the interview) should say.

Comment: If this was me, I would say that there are specialized libraries out there for the programming language I use (C#) and the runtime I use (.NET) that would help me with this. In any case, this is not a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I don't see the harm in applyig for a job which doesn't suit your qualifications exactly, which they were aware of. I have knowledge in signal processing and am searching for a way to learn more specifically in image processing and sometimes you learn best by working. Do you know of a more suitable forum for this question?

Comment: Not entirely sure. It depends on what route you want to take, if you want to talk about the programming aspect of implementing signal analysis, then SO is definitely the place if you have questions about code (but it needs to be related to code). If you have more overview-level questions about such programming, programmers.stackexchange.com might be better suited for it. However if you want to learn the math behind the signal processing and leave the programming part out of it (for now) then I would think dsp.stackexchange.com is a good fit, or possibly even one of the math-related sites.

Comment: ok thanks. I'm looking for the mathematical processing at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You failed to mention one of the things that makes it easy to identify people standing in a queue — the fact that *they aren't going anywhere* (at least, not very quickly). I'd do it something like this (Warning: contains lousy Blender graphics):

You said I could assume anything, so I'll assume that the airport's floor is a nice uniform green colour. Let's take a snapshot of the queue every 10 seconds:

[image: queue at time t=0]

[image: queue at time t=10s]

[image: queue at time t=20s]

We can use a colour range filter to identify the areas of floor that are empty in each image:

[image: empty floor area at time t=0s]

[image: empty floor area at time t=10s]

[image: empty floor area at time t=20s]

Then by calculating the maximum pixel values in each of these images, we can eliminate people who are just milling around and not part of the queue. Calculating the queue length from this image should be very easy:

[image: combined floor space images, showing queue length]

There are several ways of improving on this. For example, green might not be a good choice of colour in Dublin airport on St Patrick's day. Chequered tiles would be a little more difficult to segregate from foreground objects, but the results would be more reliable. Using an infrared camera to detect heat patterns is another alternative.

But the general approach should be fairly robust. There's absolutely no need to try and identify the outlines of individual people — this is really very difficult when people are standing close together.

Comment: Wow thank you!! this is a very helpful answer!! Just to make sure, when you said to calculate the maximum pixel in each image, did you mean  to go through sub-portions of the image, for instance every 5X5 pixel, an then choose the maximal pixel right?

Comment: No problem :-) What I meant was that you should examine each pixel position in all three images and calculate the maximum of these three values. In a graphics editor, this would be equivalent to combining all three images with the blending mode set to "lighten". This results in an image that looks like the last one shown above (with the red arrow). It will eliminate people who are walking around and not queueing, because they will be in a different position each time.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a person detector, for example OpenCV's HOG people detection:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html

or latent svm with the person model:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/latent_svm.html

I would count the number of people in the queue...

Comment: thanks Gil! that's a good answer but they didn't ask to identify the outlines of individuals in this case so it's a little over complicated for this case

Comment: I meant you can just count the number of people in the queue to know if it's crowded...

Answer (score 0):

I would estimate the color of the empty floor, and go to a normalized color space (like { R/(R+G+B), G/(R+G+B) } ). Also do this for the image you want to check, and compare these two.

My assumption: where the difference is larger than a threshold T it is due to a person.

When this is happening for too much space it is crowded and you need more clerks for check-in.

This processing will be way more robust than trying to recognize and count individual persons, and will work with quite row resolution / low amount of pixels per person.